# Android time management

Tags: android

I am now working with one database record on Android.
It now has one column storing a number and another column storing a time in millisecond.
There should be only one record.
However, the record should be refreshed at 6:00am the next day.
It means that when I want to update the number, I am supposed to check if time now is beyond the refreshing time.
Is there any simple way to achieve this checking?
I am not sure if I have explained this problem clearly. To explain in another way, I want to check if there is one "6 am" between two time stored in millisecond.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: use alarm manager for getting proper time management  and then update record with with database query in where condition put "1=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean needRefreshBean(Long milli){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(milli);
    if(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>resettime)
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,resettime);
    //cal represents the supposed refresh time
    if(cal.getTimeInMillis()<System.currentTimeMillis()){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I write a function like this. The input is the updated time stored in the database. I am not sure if this works